# Problems in converting an SQL query into vba rowsource

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

So I'm having some problems trying to populate a Listbox in Access with an SQL Query. I'm still learning VBA but this is one problem that has stumped me. I've tried fixing up my code but it the *AND-date-BETWEEN* part doesn't seem to work with my other *AND-columnname-LIKE* parts.

I was able to get the BETWEEN part to work by itself and the LIKE parts to work by themselves but not together. Here is the primary vb code that I've been trying to modify. Also DQ is another function that helps with the double quotes for the query.

```
Me.lstGngSheets.RowSource = _
 "SELECT gangID, fileName, date, crossStreets FROM tblgangSheets " & _
 "WHERE borough LIKE ""*" & DQ(Me.cboBoro.Value) & _
 "*"" AND date BETWEEN #" & txtDtBeg.Value & "# and #" & txtDtEnd.Value & "#" & _
 "*"" AND onStreet LIKE ""*" & DQ(Me.cboOnStr.Value) & _
 "*"" AND yard LIKE ""*" & DQ(Me.cboYrd.Value) & _
 "*"" AND safeStreets LIKE ""*" & DQ(Me.chkSenior.Value) & "*"""
```

Here is an SQL output that I'm trying to aim for to populate my listbox.

```
SELECT gangID, fileName, date, crossStreets
FROM tblgangSheets
WHERE borough LIKE "Queens"
AND date BETWEEN #01/1/2013# and #1/1/2014#
AND onStreet LIKE "**"
AND yard LIKE "**"
AND safeStreets LIKE "**";
```

I've been wracking my brain over this for a while, if any of you can give me advice or a solution, I would definitely appreciate it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

YOu have some weird spacing in your SQL between the date and the like's.  Try this.

```
Me.lstGngSheets.RowSource = "SELECT gangID, fileName, date, crossStreets FROM tblgangSheets " & _
 "WHERE borough LIKE ""*" & DQ(Me.cboBoro.Value) & _
 "*"" AND date BETWEEN #" & txtDtBeg.Value & "# and #" & txtDtEnd.Value & "#" & _
 " AND onStreet LIKE ""*" & DQ(Me.cboOnStr.Value) & _
 "*"" AND yard LIKE ""*" & DQ(Me.cboYrd.Value) & _
 "*"" AND safeStreets LIKE ""*" & DQ(Me.chkSenior.Value) & "*"""
```

Note that I removed the "*"" immediately after the # closing your end date.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works as desired! I didn't realize that the ""*" part also affected my statement.